# Prove the following theorem about periodic sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Another exercise from Johnsonbaugh's Foundations of Mathematical Analysis: suppose $(a_n)$ is a periodic sequence with period $p$ and $\sum_{n=1}^p a_n = 0$. If $(b_n)$ is a positive decreasing sequence converging to zero, show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n b_n$ converges. I recognize that the alternating series test follows as a special case, when $a_n = (-1)^n$, but so far I haven't seen how I can generalize the proof of that to this stronger theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions $a_n=a_{n+p}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^pa_n=0$ imply that
$$ |\sum_{n=1}^Na_k|=\Big|\sum_{n=1}^{p\lfloor \frac{N}{p}\rfloor}a_n+\sum_{n=p\lfloor \frac{N}{p}\rfloor+1}^Na_n\Big|\leq \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}|a_k| $$
for all $N\geq 1$, since any sum over a full period can be cancelled. Therefore the partial sums of $\{a_n\}$ are bounded, so we can apply [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) to conclude that $\sum_{n}a_nb_n$ converges.

Comment: Of course, forgot about Dirichlet's test. Thanks